# HTML5:Change colour of rounded rectangle on mouseover

Tags: html, css

I have created a rounded rectangle in html5. Here is the code-

```
<div style="position:absolute; width:148px; height:44px; left:90px; -webkit-border-radius: 22px;-moz-border-radius: 22px;border-radius: 22px; border:2px solid #FFFFFF; background-color:#4D0C00; cursor:pointer; top: 98px;"> </div>
```

Now I want to change the background color on mouseover. Any help??

Comment: Sorry.. by mistake it was not shown properly.. Now added it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jDWVE/)

```
<div class="divClass"> </div>

.divClass:hover{ background: red; }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<div style="position:absolute; width:148px; height:44px; left:90px; -webkit-border-radius: 22px;-moz-border-radius: 22px;border-radius: 22px; border:2px solid #FFFFFF; background-color:#4D0C00; cursor:pointer; top: 98px;"> </div>
```

Change this code. Not a good practice to use inline style.

```
<div class="myDiv"> </div>
```

Create CSS class instead for inline styles.

```
.myDiv{position:absolute;width:148px;height:44px; left:90px; -webkit-border-radius: 22px;-moz-border-radius: 22px;border-radius: 22px; border:2px solid #FFFFFF; background-color:#4D0C00; cursor:pointer; top: 98px;}

.myDiv:hover{background-color:#FF0000; /* put your color here */ }
```